# DataBinding to ComboBox in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to bind CheckedListbox's Cheched items to Combobox my code is given below

```
Private Sub chklColumns_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chklColumns.SelectedIndexChanged        
            cmbSort.DataSource = chklColumns.CheckedItems
End Sub
```

whenever I check an item first time it loads one item to the Combobox, but when I select second item still I have single item in the Combo...
am I doing anythig wrong in my above code ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reset the binding by setting the `DataSource` to `Nothing` before setting a new value:

```
Private Sub chklColumns_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chklColumns.SelectedIndexChanged        
    cmbSort.DataSource = Nothing
    cmbSort.DataSource = chklColumns.CheckedItems
End Sub
```